# Material-ui autocomplete clear value when the option is an object

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I have an object which is an array of users. Most users have the same name so I cant make it an array of string because I have to distinguish user's who have the same name with their unique id, so my object for my option is this `{ label: defineName(user), id: user.id }`. I am having issues clearing the value of the Autocomplete field because online a simpler option field which might be an array of string where i can set the value to "" if I want to clear it. I can not do it with this option type cause it crashes the web app with the `Unhandled Thrown Error!`. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
const defineName = (item: Partial<Item>): string => `${item.firstName} ${item.middleName ?? ''} ${item.lastName}`;

    <Autocomplete
              data-testid="userSelectField"
              freeSolo
              disabled={disabled}
              value={Object.keys(user).length === 0 ? { label: '', id: '' } : { label: defineName(user), id: user.id }}
              options={searchResult.items.map((item) => ({ label: defineName(item), id: item.id }))}
              fullWidth={fullWidth}
              label={label ?? t('components:citizenshipInput.label')}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option: any, value: any) => option.label === value}
              onInputChange={(e: any, value: any) => searchFn(value)}
              onChange={(e: any, value: any) => {
                const result = searchResult.items.find((item) => item.id === value.id);
                setUser(result as User);
              }}
              renderTags={(tagValue: any, getTagProps: any) => tagValue.map((option: any, index: number) => (
                  <Chip
                      label={option}
                      sx={{ marginTop: '-2px !important' }}
                      {...getTagProps({ index })}
                      size='small'
                      onDelete={undefined}
                  />
              ))
              }
              labelSx={labelSx}
          />
```

My Question is how can i clear the value selected even tho my options is a an object

Comment: In your `onChange` handler you're accessing `id` on `value`, when you clear a MUI Autocomplete, the value is set to null, si you're trying to access `id` on `null`, which crashes the page. Use a guard or just use optional chaining.

Comment: @0xts thanks, but that isnt the solution

Comment: Could you add a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?